# Add a random variable into Sed \a every new lines

Tags: random, sed, windows-subsystem-for-linux

i want to add a random number every new lines created by sed

For the moment my command is :

```
sed "a path/to/file$(($RANDOM%7))" tmp/line.txt
```

Result :

```
line1
path/to/file1
line3
path/to/file1
line5
path/to/file1
line7
path/to/file1
...(22K lines)
```

Expected :

```
line1
path/to/file1
line3
path/to/file0
line5
path/to/file7
line7
path/to/file5
...(22k lines)
```

Comment: Variable are not expanded using singel quote, try double quote.

Comment: `awk` is better suited for this kind of requirement as `awk` does have its own `rand()` function.

Comment: `awk -v seed=$(date +%s)  'BEGIN{srand(seed);}/path\/to\/file$/{sub(/ /,RS);print $0 int(rand()*7)}'  tmp/line.txt`

Comment: This might help: `seq 1 4 | sed -e "s/.*/bash -c 'echo \$((\${RANDOM}%7))'/e"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using shuf and GNU sed:

```
shuf -r -e 'path/to/file'{0..7} | sed 'R /dev/stdin' file
```

Or shuf and awk:

```
shuf -r -i 0-7 | awk '1; { getline < "/dev/stdin"; print "path/to/file" $0 }' file
```

Or just awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { srand() } 1; { print "path/to/file" int(rand() * 8) }' file
```

Comment: Sed is slower and awk looking way more complex. Thank you i will use both.